# Python Opencv crops input image from usb camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera

Im trying to create a tool that will take images from stereo cameras (connected to a sync board) with python and opencv.

When im looking at the image i get from opencv it seems different then what i get with windows camera app.

both set to the same resolution. what am i missing?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
#
# cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv2.imwrite('test.bmp',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    print('size:', width, height)
```

[image: Windows app input]

[image: Python code input]

both images are 1344x376